Why are my ECS tasks pausing for six hours on startup?
I have a Fargate ECS task that runs a Django app via gunicorn. That task successfully started a few weeks ago and had no issues. It was then replaced by routine AWS maintenance/updates. The replacement task started successfully, but it paused during the execution of the entry point script for longer than the load balancer healthcheck grace period. The task of course failed the health check and that caused ECS to again stop and replace the task. This then happened endlessly, with each replacement task having the same issue.
There have been no code changes involved in the Docker image used for the task. I obviously expected no change to the ECS task and that it would run as it did before.
After implementing the ECS task deployment circuit breaker to stop the endless task replacement cycle, I left the paused (but running) ECS task alone for a while. I realized from the Cloudwatch logs that the task pauses for exactly six hours each time while in the middle of running the entry point script. Here's the entry point script:
set -euo pipefail
cd /home/viewer/projects/server || exit
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=viewer_server.settings
export PYTHONPATH="/home/viewer/projects/server/"
echo "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE and PYTHONPATH set."
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python viewer_server/create_django_superuser.py
gunicorn --timeout 120 --graceful-timeout 120 --workers 3 --bind :80 viewer_server.wsgi:application

Here's an excerpt from the Cloudwatch logs:
2024-06-10T08:44:37.294Z    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE and PYTHONPATH set.
2024-06-10T14:44:40.849Z    No changes detected 
2024-06-10T20:44:43.978Z    Running migrations:
2024-06-10T20:44:43.978Z    No migrations to apply.
2024-06-10T20:44:44.654Z    Django superuser already exists.
2024-06-10T20:44:44.871Z    Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2024-06-10T20:44:44.871Z    Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:80 (769)
2024-06-10T20:44:44.871Z    Using worker: sync
2024-06-10T20:44:44.874Z    Booting worker with pid: 771
2024-06-10T20:46:46.181Z    WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:771)
2024-06-10T20:46:46.182Z    Worker exiting (pid: 771)
2024-06-10T20:46:46.542Z    Booting worker with pid: 782
2024-06-10T20:48:47.609Z    WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:782)
2024-06-10T20:48:47.610Z    Worker exiting (pid: 782)

There are more gunicorn workers, but I cut the log down a bit for readability. They all do the same thing. I verified the worker timeout is from the load balancer healthcheck GET request by enabling gunicorn DEBUG level logging. Seemingly, the pause during the Django command resulted in a non-working web server for some reason, despite applying no migrations.
The only ECS-related reference to six hours in the AWS docs I have found is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/bestpracticesguide/security-iam-roles.html
The IAM role is the same as it always was, so I am unsure how that could be related. In an attempt to at least get the ECS task to work at all, I was trying to figure out how to refresh the temporarily credentials the task gets from its IAM role. But I've been unable to figure out how to make that work either.
Any help would be appreciated!
[Edit]
I also set the Django verbosity on both commands to level 3 (debug). There is no log output from either Django command before or during each pause.

I've never seen anything like this before, and I have quite a few things running on ECS, including some Django applications. It seems to me that there is something happening in your Django code, some attempted connection to an external resource or something, that is hanging and timing out. I would try increasing the logging level of your Django application as much as possible to see if you can get any more details.

@MarkB I forgot to mention that in my original post. I also set the Django verbosity on both commands to level 3 (debug). No output is produced during the 6 hour pause during either command.

Please provide a [mre], I can only assume you have certain code that's either waiting for some time or trying to do something that takes that much time. Do note though there's certain (potentially unrelated) things your entrypoint script should not be doing though. For example makemigrations is something your entrypoint should not run. Any migrations that need to be generated should be made outside of your container and committed to version control.

@AbdulAzizBarkat can you be more specific about what to add so that you would consider it an MRE? The only additional piece I could add is the Dockerfile contents, I suppose. There is definitely a limit to what I can share though, due to some confidentiality.
And yes, a bit off topic, but I would not normally run either makemigrations or migrate inside of the ECS task entry point script. However, the Django setup is coming from code that we do not internally maintain. It's something we plan to address another time.

@Mibe no idea, but what you've shared is not an MRE. There's nothing in that script or logs that would tell us what's causing the 6 hour delay. If I were you I'd start off by sprinkling echo in that script and then logging in the Python code. The cause of the delay would be after the last log before the delay.

@AbdulAzizBarkat I edited my post to be more clear - there is no log output from either Django command before or during the pause (even when I increase the Django verbosity to debug level). I think what I am looking for here is (a) has anyone experienced a 6 hour delay in an ECS task before and (b) is there a reason that would happen due to how ECS works? This is more of an ECS question and less of a Django question.

Do you have a post_migrate signal or pre_migrate signal registered in any of your apps that might run after migrations by any chance? And no, I am not talking about logs that your code already do but instead about adding more logs into your code for debugging purposes.
